# npm installation eroor on fresh laravel 8 app

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-8, npm-install, laragon

I am using laragon. Created a fresh laravel 8 app. Installed Jetstream and livewire. Then tried running npm install && npm run dev. but getting error.
[image]

I have tried Delete `node_module`s folder and `package-lock.json`
reinstall package using `npm install`

Cleared npm cache
Tried run `npm run dev` again but didn't help.

my package.json

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```

My log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\laragon\\bin\\nodejs\\node-v14\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\laragon\\bin\\nodejs\\node-v14\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\laragon\www\school\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;;C:\laragon\bin\laragon\utils;C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.33-winx64\bin;C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64;C:\laragon\bin\composer;C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.47-win64-VS16\bin;C:\laragon\bin\redis\redis-x64-3.2.100;C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14;C:\laragon\bin\nginx\nginx-1.19.10;C:\laragon\bin\notepad++;C:\laragon\bin\telnet;C:\laragon\bin\ngrok;C:\laragon\bin\git\bin;C:\laragon\bin\git\cmd;C:\laragon\bin\git\usr\bin;C:\laragon\bin\git\mingw64\bin;C:\laragon\bin;C:\laragon\usr\bin;C:\laragon\bin\cmder\bin;C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64;C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.3-nts-Win32-vs16-x64;C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\vim\vim74;C:\laragon\bin\cmder\;
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\laragon\www\school
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v14\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\laragon\www\school
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\laragon\\bin\\nodejs\\node-v14\\node.exe" "C:\\laragon\\bin\\nodejs\\node-v14\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.12
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: cmd error i am getting:

https://ibb.co/gMNJxyk

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Mix CLI. Inside scripts use...

```
"scripts": {
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "production": "mix --production"
}
```